# Programmatically delete a webform submission by sid without first loading it

Tags: 8, webforms

Drupal 8 project has a 2 webforms:

- Webform "ABC"
- Webform "123"

**Explanation of the process:**

When Webform "ABC" is submitted, a new "node" is created and the "Sid" used to create this node is recorded inside a "text" field (field_submission_sid) on this created node.

Now, when Webform "123" is loaded, the value of (field_submission_sid) is populated inside a 'text' element (submission_to_delete)... and when the Webform "123" is submitted, a **custom handler** will delete the submission of **sid value = (submission_to_delete)**

The custom handler is working but I believe there is a better solution... so please I need your help ?

**Custom handler:**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_module\Plugin\WebformHandler;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Serialization\Yaml;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

use Drupal\webform\WebformInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase;
use Drupal\webform\webformSubmissionInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission;


/**
 * Delete a 'webform Submission' using its "SID" retrieved from a populated webform submission value.
 *
 * @WebformHandler(
 *   id = "Delete a webform Submission using its sid",
 *   label = @Translation("Delete a webform Submission using its sid"),
 *   category = @Translation("Entity Delete"),
 *   description = @Translation("Delete a webform Submission using its sid retrieved from a populated webform submission valu"),
 *   cardinality = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
 *   results = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::RESULTS_PROCESSED,
 *   submission = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::SUBMISSION_REQUIRED,
 * )
 */

class DeleteSidWebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */

  // Function to be fired while submitting the Webform.
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
    // Get an array of the values from the submission.
    $values = $webform_submission->getData();

    // Load 'submission' object from webform-submission populated data. 
    //get (SID) from (submission_to_delete) text element available on the webform
    $sid = $values["submission_to_delete"];
    $webform_submission = \Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission::load($sid);

    //Delete the Submission
    $webform_submission->delete();
 }
}
```

**If you notice, I am loading the submission first then i am deleting it...**

is there a better solution where I can delete the submission directly without first have to load it ?
maybe something like `$webform_submission = \Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission::delete(submission_to_delete);`

**UPDATE:**

I noticed if the 'webform submission' is not available (Ex: An admin deleted by mistake) so the value of `$sid` will be `NULL` and the below error is generated:

```
Error: Call to a member function delete() on null in Drupal\custom_module\Plugin\WebformHandler\DeleteSidWebformHandler->submitForm()
```

How to add an **if statement** to check if **$sid value is empty** then do nothing otherwise **execute code**.

Thank you,

Comment: You always need to load before delete, there is no "better" solution.

Comment: mmmm thank you @NoSssweat because I am affraid from affecting the performance of the website since the above handler will be executed a lot

Comment: @NoSssweat can you please add your above comment and an **if statement** as per my above update to an answer so I can mark it as the right answer!

Comment: Whew! This question put me on the right path to solve my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always need to load before delete, there is no "better" solution.

> I am affraid from affecting the performance of the website since the
>   above handler will be executed a lot

Loading one entity at a time is no performance issue whatsoever.

```
$webform_submission = \Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission::load($sid);
// Check if submission is returned.
if (!empty($webform_submission)) {
  //Delete the Submission
  $webform_submission->delete();
}
```